# How to sample a Flux periodically using project reactor?

Tags: reactive-programming, project-reactor

My current attempt is below, but this only prints a single value. I would like the sampling to continue periodically so that a value is printed every second. How to do this?

```
import org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.Logger;
import reactor.core.publisher.Flux;

import java.time.Duration;

public class Test {
    private static final Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger(Test.class);

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Flux.<String>create(sink -> sink.next("HEARTBEAT"))
                .sample(Flux.interval(Duration.ofSeconds(1)))
                .subscribe(logger::info);

        try {
            Thread.sleep(10000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The *sampling* in your example does continue periodically - it will sample every second. However, your original `Flux.create` call only ever creates a single value, so there's only ever one to sample!

If you replace your `Flux.create()` with `Flux.generate()`, it'll stream "HEARTBEAT" constantly, and your sampling will thus work as expected.